# Changing Schema Names of all tables in EDMX

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, edmx

I recently moved all the tables in SQL Server to a new schema, lets say **XYZ**. Now I want to update my edmx, to refer to tables that are under new schema **XYZ**. How do I do that? All it allows me currently is to add all the tables from the **XYZ** schema to the edmx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little-known fact is that the `edmx` file is **xml** and so can be edited as text, as well as using the designer tool.

In Visual Studio you can right-click it in Solution Explorer and choose `Open With...` to get to the xml. Once in there, search for `Schema=` and you will find the section with all the database table references. Change these as required and save.

Comment: i figured it out myself after I opened it in xml editor. thanks.